# Rails 4: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I'm working on an old Rails 4 project and I'm having problem when running `bundle install` and `bundle update` command.

Here are the logs:

```
Resolving dependencies..................................................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_link_to was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      actionpack

    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.4) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.8)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.2) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 0.11.2) was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.2.8)

    validate_url was resolved to 1.0.8, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    active_median (~> 0.1.3) was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
      activerecord

    activerecord-nulldb-adapter was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 2.0.0)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.8)

    rails-erd was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2)

    seed_dump was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    activesupport-json_encoder (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0, < 5.0)

    carrierwave (~> 0.11.2) was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    intercom-rails was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      activesupport (> 3.0)

    jbuilder (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.9.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    mailjet was resolved to 1.5.4, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.1.0)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.8)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.2) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)

    seed_dump was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "carrierwave":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 0.11.2)

    carrierwave-base64 (~> 2.3) was resolved to 2.8.1, which depends on
      carrierwave (>= 0.8.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
        i18n (~> 0.7)

    faker was resolved to 2.11.0, which depends on
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.8)

    secondbase (~> 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.6, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.0)

    two_factor_authentication (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.1.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0)

    two_factor_authentication (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      devise was resolved to 4.7.1, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.1.0)

    font-awesome-rails was resolved to 4.7.0.5, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.1)

    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.4) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.5, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.2.0)

    momentjs-rails (~> 2.15, >= 2.15.1) was resolved to 2.20.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1)

    quiet_assets was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.8)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.2) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rake":
  In Gemfile:
    rake (~> 12.0)

    capistrano-figaro was resolved to 1.0.0.0, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.13.0, which depends on
        rake (>= 10.0.0)

    rails (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.8, which depends on
        rake (>= 0.8.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby (~> 2.4.1.0)

    sidekiq was resolved to 6.0.7, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.5.0)
```

And, this is my RVM env (I'm on OSX 10.12.6):

```
rvm env
export PATH="/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1'
export GEM_PATH='/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1:/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1'
export IRBRC='/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.4.1'
```

And, [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/f73AH5zE) is my `bundle env` output.

How to read these logs and what I should do to fix them? Any tips?

Comment: Are you running install or update? Did this project come with the lock file? Make sure install succeeds using the lock file that was there before you before trying to update anything, and update one dependency at a time.

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile please

Comment: It strongly looks like your Gemfile is corrupted. As the error states, it contains incompatible dependencies. You have Rails 4, but other dependencies depend on Rails 2.x or Rails 3.x...